# Starting with C, struct and function simple program, returned data problably wrong

Tags: c, function, struct

I'm starting to learn in C and now I'm in the chapters of structs so I'm making a simple program with switch who ask for input from the user if the user press "1" the program ask for data of a new client, and after that you can print it from another function called in a switch case "2", the problem is the printed data is totally wrong I suspect the returned data is wrong or so.

P.D: Exist any way to print only the data introduced before instead 20 times the same data?

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct datos{
        char nombre[20];
        char apellido[20];
        char direccion[20];
        int edad[3];
        long telefono[10];
}agenda;

agenda mostrar_datos();
agenda insercion_datos();

int main(void)
{
    char con[3];

    int menu;

     puts("\n=== Bienvenido a la agenda en C ===\n"); 
     while (!strstr(con,"si"))
    {
        puts("\n=== Que quieres hacer? ===\n");
        fflush(stdin);    
        puts("\nIntroducir datos [1]\n");
        puts("\nVer los datos[2]\n"); 
        puts("\nSalir[3]\n");  
        scanf(" %d", &menu);
        switch(menu)
        {
        case 1:           
           insercion_datos();
           break;

        case 2:           
           mostrar_datos();
           break;
        }
    }
}

agenda insercion_datos()
{
    agenda nuevo_dato;

    puts("Bienvenido, vamos a introducir datos.");
    puts("Dime su nombre.");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(nuevo_dato.nombre);
    puts("Dime su apellido.");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(nuevo_dato.apellido);
    puts("Dime su direccion.");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(nuevo_dato.direccion);
    puts("Dime su edad.");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf(" %d", &nuevo_dato.edad);
    puts("Dime su telefono.");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf(" %d", &nuevo_dato.telefono);
}

agenda mostrar_datos()
{
    int i = 0;
    agenda mostrar_dato;

    for (i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        printf("Nombre: %s\n Apellido: %s\n Direccion: %s\n Edad: %d\n Telefono: %d\n", mostrar_dato.nombre,mostrar_dato.apellido,
         mostrar_dato.direccion,mostrar_dato.edad, mostrar_dato.telefono);
    }
}
```

Comment: the loop goes infinitely, `con` is never changed

Comment: `fflush` is meant for files opened for writing, hence not `stdin`.

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` is undefined behaviour.

Comment: For formatting code here, you probably want to remove consecutive blank lines as well as make sure your indenting is consistent so that your code is more readable.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this will work.

Couple of points to note here:

1. There is a white space in the scanf statement where you try to read the `menu` variable in the `main()`
2. In your function: insercion_datos() does not do anything besides creating a local variable and filling it with some data.
3. In your function: mostrar_datos(), the local variable is not initialized, therefore you receive no output.

Try to make a global array of `agenda' and then fill the array of structure everytime you read an input through insercion_datos(). Keep track of the number of inserts you have performed

the when you are printing using the mostrar_datos(), you can use that count and print.

I hope this resolves your doubt as to why there are no returns.

Comment: Please make changes suggested by @Alter Mann too. Those will help you read appropriate values.

Comment: Provide an option to exit the application too. Make that as case 3.